# Match full line

Tags: vba, ms-word, visual-studio-macros

I want to match a full line containing a word, say its 'josh'

```
"^13*<josh>[!^13]@^13"
```

doesnt match anything in my document:

> Josh
>
> Joshd
>
> adf Josh
>
> fffJoshfff

Comment: By match do you mean select the entire line which contains 'Josh'?

Comment: yes exactly...been experimenting but cant quite find what i want

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the wildcards option in the UI, or set .MatchWIldCards in the Find object if you are in VBA. Even then,

- Word's "regex" is not the same as "real regex"
- You won't get "lines" but "paragraphs" using ^13
- I think you will get more than you want with that initial "^13*". The following may work better - can't be sure.

  ^13[!^13]@[!^13]@^13